# Why is there no update for Firefox?

Tags: updates, firefox

Firefox 85.0 was released 6 days ago and still there is no update.

Is something wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: The advice is to wait... it will be available soon but if you must have it [this](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/01/mozilla-firefox-85-released-with-enhanced-privacy-protection/) link shows how to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Canonical has been slow to package the update. You can check the current status of any official package at `packages.ubuntu.com`. For example,

https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/firefox

It currently tells that the latest available package for 20.04 LTS is

`84.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`

If you want to know why it's taking longer than expected, you probably have to search for it in `launchpad.net`. For example, according to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/
version 85 has been in `proposed` state since 2021-01-18 but for some reason it has not yet entered `main` repository which you probably have enabled.

If you want Firefox updates faster than the usual Canonical QA process can handle, you probably want to add PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

However, note their description:

> Staging PPA for Mozilla and other browser-related security updates.
> Unless you are testing updates, you should NOT install packages from
> this PPA.

After searching for "firefox 85" in bugs, I found this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/cargo/+bug/1901571

It seems that building new Firefox packages requires upgrading `rustc` and `cargo`, too, which requires those dependencies to be upgraded before Firefox can be upgraded. This is an another example where Ubuntu is getting hurt for not being rolling release distribution and at the same time still trying to keep Firefox updated to latest version. They end up requiring to upgrade some other packages, too, but because this is not officially allowed by no-rolling-release rules they get extra delays for cases like this because they need to coordinate all changes across multiple packages.

If there were some important security patches, those would be handled separately and backported manually if needed to avoid such stalls.